# javascript dependencies causing link_to method: :destroy issuing a GET request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, navbar

### Update (26 February 2015):

jPushMenu.js had a handler that was making a `e.preventDefault()` call.  If I removed this one line event handler, I stopped seeing the bad behavior.  jPushMenu also has a new version of their code out now that does not use this `e.preventDefault()` call, which also fixes my issue.  The question is below for anyone that runs into a similar problem, but likely not as their is a new version.

### Question:

I'm having trouble with a link that I specify the `method: :delete` for in the `link_to` helper like this:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to raw('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sign out'), 
              signout_path, 
              method: :delete %>
</li>
```

Even though I specify the `method: :delete` like above, and the rendered HTML does include the `data-method="delete"` attribute, clicking the link issues a `GET` request.

This has never been an issue up until I added the following file to my `app/assets/javascripts/` directory: [jPushMenu.js](http://takien.github.io/jPushMenu/js/jPushMenu.js).  As you can see below, I'm including this file through the application javascript manifest file with the line `//= require_tree .`.  Basically, my signout link broke as soon as I added a different, mobile friendly bootstrap-styled navbar.

I would really like to find out how to make the push menu navbar work while also allowing my signout link to work as it did before, but I don't know what else I'm missing here.  One thing I'm afraid of is that I have so many javascript files that something might be stomping over the other and maybe the order in which I load them in matters finally?  Does anyone else have any ideas why this may be the case?

### In regards to other StackOverflow questions that are similar:

You'll notice that my link is in a `<li>...</li>` tag.  This is because this link appears in a bootstrap styled dropdown in my nav header object.  Other StackOverflow questions (the majority of them I could find actually) suggest that using a `button_to` helper rather than a `link_to` helper will solve the problem.  And it definitely works.  But now I have an odd looking button in my dropdown and all the bootstrap styling is ignoring this part of the dropdown because it is looking for an `<a>` tag, not an `<button style="button">` tag.

**More directed question: Where would be a good place to debug this?  If Rails handles the `data-method` attribute and uses javascript to issue a DELETE request, what part of the application code can I put a breakpoint?**

(below are files and output that you may or may not want to look at...)

### application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require bootstrap-select
//= require bootstrap-tokenfield
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require fullcalendar
//= require fullcalendar/gcal
//= require_tree .
...
```

### Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.2'

gem 'rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bootstrap_form'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'state_machine'
gem 'twitter_cldr'
gem 'pg'

gem 'figaro'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'mail_form'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'momentjs-rails'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails'
gem 'date_validator'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'bootstrap-select-rails'
gem 'fullcalendar-rails'
gem 'wepay'
gem 'omnicontacts', '~> 0.3.5', git: 'git://github.com/Diego81/omnicontacts.git'
gem 'rails4-autocomplete'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'mail'

gem 'mailboxer'

gem 'bootstrap_tokenfield_rails'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.14.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'meta_request'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

### routes.rb

```
...
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: 'delete'
...
```

### Output of `rake routes`

```
...
sessions     POST    /sessions(.:format)      sessions#create
new_session  GET     /sessions/new(.:format)  sessions#new
session      DELETE  /sessions/:id(.:format)  sessions#destroy
...
```

Comment: I've had this issue before. It turned out that my javascript file was not being correctly loaded. You're right that this is related to javascript.

Comment: Yea, I've been reading lots of `StackOverflow` questions about it and most of the people with this problem had there issues solved by adding jquery (which mine is at the very top of my `application.js` file).  I can't imagine why, but the javascript associated with the jPushMenu seems to have broken it.  I just don't understand how a client side javascript file could affect my requests...

Comment: @MikeC, what javascript file wasn't being loaded correctly for you?  And how did you get it to load correctly?

Comment: My case was kind of different form yours. The problem was that the layout was not including the javascript manifest file.

Comment: Oh okay.  Thanks anyway!  If you think of anything else, let me know?  Also, I'll make sure to post the answer if I find it before someone else does in case you are interested!

Comment: Any javascript errors when you load the page?

Comment: negative.  There were some related to my google maps when I visited that particular page, but this signout link appears in the navbar that is available on every page accessible by a logged in user.  I have also seen glyphicon errors for months...

Comment: One interesting test would be to rename the file as require tree loads by name. Do you get different behaviour when you rename it to 'ajPushMenu.js' to when it's named  'zjPushMenu.js'?

Comment: Can you post your log file result for when you try to run the destroy method?

Comment: jPushMenu has a more recent release and the problem has gone away.  There was a preventDefault call being made that if I removed manually fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jPushMenu.js had a handler that was making a e.preventDefault() call. If I removed this one line event handler, I stopped seeing the bad behavior. jPushMenu also has a new version of their code out now that does not use this e.preventDefault() call, which also fixes my issue. The question is below for anyone that runs into a similar problem, but likely not as their is a new version.